# ActiveRecord query using a joins and where. How do I build it?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have this query. I am trying to find a house with no address but with a person with an address. A house belongs to an address and a person has many addresses. A house belongs to a person and a person has many houses.

The model names are `House`, `Person`, and `Address`.

```
House.joins(:person).where('houses.address.id = ? and persons.address_id = ?', 'nil', 'not nil')
```

This query above is wrong but probably what I want. How do I construct it? My SQL isn't very good.

Comment: You would have to give us more information about the underlying tables. What are the table's names? What columns allow the join between the house and person tables?

Comment: I think you can use people, instead of persons. Rails supports some irregular plurals.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
House.joins(:persons).where(address: nil).where.not(persons: {address: nil})
```

Comment: Just run the query in the `rails console`, see the generated query and fix it to your need. You have the key parts here: `joins`, `where.not`, etc.